# Question on harmonic conjugates and Liouville's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)=u+iv$ is entire, and the harmonic function $u(x,y)$ has an upper bound. Then how to show that $u(x,y)$ must be constant throughout the plane?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $g(z):=e^{f(z)}=e^{u(z)}e^{iv(z)}$ is entire and bounded. So by [Liouville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29)...?